# How do I activate an mu-plugin with WP-CLI?

Tags: wp-cli, mu-plugins

Do I need some extra WP-CLI bundle to activate mu-plugins via command line? I can't find anything about that in the docs. Are mu-plugins treated differently by WP-CLI?

I created `/wp-content/mu-plugins/my-plugin.php` containing:

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: My Plugin
  Description: Provide must-use code.
  Version: 1.0
*/
```

When I do:

```
$ wp plugin list
```

I get:

> ```
> +---------------+----------+--------+---------+
> | name          | status   | update | version |
> +---------------+----------+--------+---------+
> | akismet       | inactive | none   | 4.0.8   |
> | hello         | active   | none   | 1.7     |
> | my-plugin     | must-use | none   | 1.0     |
> +---------------+----------+--------+---------+
> ```

But when I do:

```
$ wp plugin activate my-plugin
```

I get:

> ```
> Warning: The 'my-plugin' plugin could not be found.
> Error: No plugins activated.
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mu-plugins` don’t get activated. They’re activated just by being in that folder.